# ESS: are there "special" breakpoints for pipes?

Tags: ess, r, pipe

The [ESS Manual](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html) announces a new feature as of v16.04:

> ESS[R]: New specialized breakpoints for debugging magrittr pipes

However there is no other mention of these "specialized" breakpoints in the rest of the manual. How are they toggled? How do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user's point of view there is no special breakpoint. You just insert a breakpoint as usual with `C-t b` in the middle of an R pipeline (either involving the base pipe `|>` or the magrittr pipe `%>%`). In the Emacs buffer, that "specialized" breakpoint has the same appearance as a "regular" one. Once the debugger reaches a breakpoint in a pipeline, the value at that point is mapped to variable `x`, which you can then manipulate.